# Starting new enumitem list at level 3 (enumiii)

Tags: enumitem

I am using the `enumitem` package. I entered the following in the preamble:

```
\renewlist{enumerate}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\textbf{(\alph*)}},ref=\alph*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\textbf{(\arabic*)}},ref=\theenumi.\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\textbf{(\Alph*)}},ref=\theenumii.\Alph*}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label={\textbf{(\roman*)}},ref=\theenumiii.\roman*}
\setlist[enumerate,5]{label={\textbf{(\arabic*)}},ref=\theenumiv.\arabic*, left=\parindent}
```

Everything works fine unless I want to start a new list at a different level, say level 3 (enumiii). I cannot find a way to do that easily. Is it possible?

Comment: As always on the site please provide a full minimal example others can copy and test as it. Your code suggests you are using `enumitem` but this is not even mentioned in the sniplet, thus why we ask for a full but minimal example,

Answer (score 3):

The list nesting depth is in the count register `\@enumdepth` so if for some strange reason you need to fake already being inside a list use `\@enumdepth=2`  and it will start the next list as if nested to level 3

Comment: I tried using that, but it produced this error message:

You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode. \@

Comment: @Gerard you need to be in a package or use `\makeatletter` to use any command with `@` in its name (but why do you want to do this?)

Comment: I need to quote portions of an existing list in my documents, and this seems like the easiest way to do it. I thought it would be easy to tell enumerate to start a list at level enumiii, but it isn't.

Comment: @Gerard you just need \makeatletter\@enumdepth=2 \makeatother  before the list if I understand you correctly